# Ways to include a page in PHP and replace all the variables in it?

Tags: php, include, php-include

For example, I have a page called `'include.php'` or `'include.html'`, which contains the following lines of code:

```
<h1>Hi {$yourname}, this is a header.</h1>
```

Now, I want to include this page using PHP on another page, let's say on `'index.php'` using:

```
<?
 $yourname = 'Bir';
 include 'include.php';
 ?>
```

When I include it, the page shows:

```
<h1>Hi {$yourname}, this is a header.</h1>
```

The variable **$yourname** is not replaced by it's value `"Bir"`.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You could always just use `<?= $yourname ?>` instead of `<?php echo $yourname ?>`

Comment: There exists some template engines which might fit your syntax.

Comment: Can you provide some links if possible? @MarkusMalkusch

Comment: Sorry, my times in PHP are long gone you have to do the research on your own. I remember [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) might be one candidate.

Comment: @user3382146 Smarty was already mentioned below. It's a pretty common one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way..

**`test1.php`**

```
<?php
$var="<h1>Hi $yourname, this is a header.</h1>"; //Removed {}
```

**`test2.php`**

```
<?php
$yourname="Jacob";
include_once('test1.php');
echo $var; //"prints" <h1>Hi Jacob, this is a header.</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to write in `include.php` as

```
<h1>Hi <?php echo $yourname ;?>, this is a header.</h1>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid <? and ?>... ?

Comment: @user3382146 sure, you can echo the whole line in one go: `<?php echo "<h1>Hi {$yourname}, this is a header.</h1>";`

Comment: You can read the contents of the file include.php the replace the {$yourname} with your $yourname variable using fread function.In that case you do not need to include the file.

Comment: he still got the php tags then. You can use a template engine like smarty.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.php.net/str_replace, and replace wherever you see `{$yourname}` with what ever the value really is.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid `<?php ?>` then you have to use code like this

```
 <?php echo "<h1>Hi ".$yourname." this is a header.</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<h1>Hi <?= $yourname ?>, this is a header.</h1>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason this should be downvoted. +1 from me because downvoter didn't write any comment.

Comment: @Mike, That's true. Maybe the downvoter hates short tags in PHP.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran well they *are* discouraged even in the docs. Personally I don't use them or even recommend them, but meh. They are still part of the PHP code and until they are deprecated or removed, I don't see it as *that* big of a deal. But again, I don't agree with downvoting without leaving a comment.